# sending php email with gmail xampp not working

Tags: php, gmail

but whenever i submit execute the file, the email is not sent to my gmail.

I have already changed the php.ini in xampp in which the sendmail_path does not start with the ";".

In the sendemail.ini i have also changed the smtpp_server to smtp.gmail.com. as well as the smtp port to 587(tried 465 too). lastly i changed the auth_username and auth_password to my email and pw. but the code still does not work.

i am using windows 8

```
<?php
mail('hello.3i@gmail.com', 'sample mail', 'sample content', 'From: freak@freakzoid.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure sendmail.ini by the following if you would like to send mail from localhost.

> You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail
>   package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can
>   easily send mail from localhost.
>
> for example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and
>   `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.   in
>   `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the
>   semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for
>   gmail for localhost.
>
> in php.ini file find `[mail function]` and change
>
> ```
> SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
> smtp_port=587
> sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
> sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
> ```
>
> Now Open `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`. Replace all the existing
>   code in sendmail.ini with following code
>
> ```
> [sendmail]
>
> smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
> smtp_port=587
> error_logfile=error.log
> debug_logfile=debug.log
> auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
> auth_password=my-gmail-password
> force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
> ```
>
> Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail
>   from localhost.
>
> PS: don't forgot to replace **my-gmail-id** and  **my-gmail-password**
>   in above code. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you
>   copied settings from above. For example comment following line if
>   there is another **sendmail_path** :
>   `sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"` in the php.ini
>   file
>
> Also remember to restart the server using the XAMMP control panel so
>   the changes take effect.

Comment: hi, after i execute the php file with mail function. the mail ends up in my mailoutput folder in xampp. do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Should configure SMTP.
`C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` and `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Also, you can use the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) easily:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```